# Presentation Figure Not Working

Tags: errors, presentations

When I try this code I get an error saying that I have an :

> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

```
\subsection{Energy}
\begin{frame}{Energy}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1]{Energy_Intensity.jpg}
\caption{\label{fig:energy}Particle Energy versus Particle Flux}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a unit in width:

```
\subsection{Energy}
\begin{frame}{Energy}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{Energy_Intensity.jpg}
\caption{\label{fig:energy}Particle Energy versus Particle Flux}
\end{figure}
```

If you want specific width you can modify this value and also use some latex internal value as `\textwidth`

The error says that `1` is not a legal mesure. So he inserted `pt` to a have a legal mesure: `1pt`.